# Estimote indoor location list can't work

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, estimote

I use Estimote indoor location example to make the location list. But the location list is null. I think the problem that is the App can't find my estimote cloud. Please tell me how to solve the problem.

Code:

```
 weak var weakSelf:ListViewController? = self
    let onSuccess:(AnyObject!) -> (Void) =
    { (locations:AnyObject!) in
        weakSelf!.ownLocationsArray = locations as! NSMutableArray
        weakSelf!.tableView.reloadData()
        weakSelf!.hadError = false;
        self.finishedSectionRefresh() 
    }
self.manager.fetchUserLocationsWithSuccess(onSuccess, failure: onFailure)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

In order for the app to "find" your Estimote Cloud account, you need to use `ESTConfig`'s `setupAppID:andAppToken:` method. You can generate the token on:

https://cloud.estimote.com/#/apps/add/your-own-app

Since you're writing in Swift, you might have to add `#import <EstimoteSDK/EstimoteSDK.h>` to your Objective-C Bridging Header, so that your app gains access to the `ESTConfig` class.

Comment: I have used ESTConfig's setupAppID:andAppToken already.But the App still can't find my estimote cloud.

Comment: Do you get any error message? Is the `failure` block being called, or the `success` block?

Comment: weakSelf!.ownLocationsArray = locations as! NSMutableArray  Threat1:break point 4.1